# scan function output varies

Tags: r, scanf

Dear All R Developers,

I maintain a package GENEAread and have recently found a bug in the package which comes from within the function header.info. This function is designed to read in the header information stored in a GENEActiv binary file, from the Actigraphy watch GENEActiv. This information is stored in the first 100 lines of the binary file.

The part of this function that is reading in values incorrectly uses the function scan(). Until recently this has worked, however the frequency which is read in by the function header.info now takes a different form because of the varying output of scan() that now occurs.

Below is some sample code which demonstrates the issue:

```
install.packages(“GENEAread”)
library(GENEAread)
binfile = system.file("binfile/TESTfile.bin", package = "GENEAread")[1]

nobs = 300

info <- vector("list", 15)
#    index <- c(2, 20:22, 26:29)
tmpd = readLines(binfile, 300)

 #try to find index positions - so will accomodate multiple lines in the 
 notes sections
 #change when new version of binfile is produced.
 ind.subinfo = min(which((tmpd == "Subject Info" )& (1:length(tmpd) >= 37)))
 ind.memstatus = max(which(tmpd == "Memory Status"))
 ind.recdata = (which(tmpd == "Recorded Data"))
 ind.recdata = ind.recdata[ind.recdata > ind.memstatus][1:2]
 ind.calibdata = max(which(tmpd == "Calibration Data"))
 ind.devid = min(which(tmpd == "Device Identity"))
 ind.config = min(which(tmpd == "Configuration Info"))
 ind.trial = min(which(tmpd == "Trial Info"))

 index = c(ind.devid + 1, ind.recdata[1] + 8, ind.config + 2:3, ind.trial + 
 1:4, ind.subinfo + 1:7, ind.memstatus + 1)

 if (max(index) == Inf){
    stop("Corrupt headers or not Geneactiv file!", call = FALSE)
 }

 # Read in header info
 nm <- NULL

 for (i in 1:length(index)) {
    line = strsplit(tmpd[index[i]], split = ":")[[1]]
    el = ""
    if (length(line) > 1){
       el <- paste(line[2:length(line)],collapse=":")
    }
    info[[i]] <- el
    nm[i] <- paste(strsplit(line[1], split = " ")[[1]], collapse = "_")
 }

 info <- as.data.frame(matrix(info), row.names = nm)
 colnames(info) <- "Value"

 Decimal_Separator = "."

 if (length( grep(",", paste(tmpd[ind.memstatus + 8:9], collapse = "")) ) > 0){
   Decimal_Separator = ","
 }

 info = rbind(info,
         Decimal_Separator = Decimal_Separator)
 # more here
 # if (more){
 # grab calibration data etc as well
 calibration = list()
 fc = file(binfile, "rt")

 index = sort(c(ind.config + 4,
                ind.calibdata + 1:8,
                ind.memstatus + 1,
                ind.recdata + 3,
                ind.recdata[1] + c(2,8))
              )


 #### First appearance in the function header.info of the function scan. ####
 # tmp <- substring(scan(fc,
 #                       skip = index[1] - 1,
 #                       what = "",
 #                       n = 3,
 #                       sep = " ",
 #                       quiet = TRUE)[3],
 #                  c(1,2,5),
 #                  c(1, 3, 6))

 # Isolating scan and running multiple times #

scan(fc,
     skip = index[1] - 1,
     what = "",
     n = 3,
     sep = " ",
     quiet = TRUE)[3]

scan(fc,
     skip = index[1] - 1,
     what = "",
     n = 3,
     sep = " ",
     quiet = TRUE)[3]

scan(fc,
     skip = (index[1] - 1),
     what = "",
     n = 3,
     sep = " ",
     quiet = TRUE)[3]

#### Checking the same thing happens with the substring ####
# Checking by using 3.4.3 possibly
substring(scan(fc,
               skip = index[1] - 1,
               what = "",
               n = 3,
               sep = " ",
               quiet = TRUE)[3],
          c(1,2,5),
          c(1, 3, 6))

substring(scan(fc,
               skip = index[1] - 1,
               what = "",
               n = 3,
               sep = " ",
               quiet = TRUE)[3],
          c(1,2,5),
          c(1, 3, 6))

substring(scan(fc,
               skip = index[1] - 1,
               what = "",
               n = 3,
               sep = " ",
               quiet = TRUE)[3],
          c(1,2,5),
          c(1, 3, 6))
```

Why does the output of the scan function vary? I have run the examples given on the scan help page and the output is the same if the code is ran more than once. What in the build up to running this function can cause the output to vary?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We don't have access to the `TESTfile.bin` file, so it's not really possible to debug this.  Could you put a sample file online somewhere, and show us minimal code that generates inconsistent results?

Comment: The file is located inside the package GENEAread. If you run: 
install.packages("GENEAread")
library(GENEAread) 
Then you will have access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You opened the `fc` connection using

```
fc = file(binfile, "rt")
```

This means `scan()` will read from it and leave it open, with the file pointer advanced to the end of the read.  Each time you call `scan()`, you are reading a later part of the file.  That's why the results vary.

If you want to always read the same part of the file, you would do it something like this:

```
seek(fc, 0)
scan(fc, ...)

seek(fc, 0)
scan(fc, ...)
```

Alternatively, don't open `fc` when you create it, and `scan()` will open and close it each time.  You do this by writing

```
fc <- file(binfile)  # No open specified
```

Or even more simply (but a tiny bit less efficiently)

```
fc <- binfile
```

which will create a new connection each time.